# How to reference the last column in pivot_longer() without naming it or providing the index number?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, tidyr, reshape

I'm writing a function to pivot a data table to long format. For the `cols =`  argument, the name of the first column will always be the same, but the final column (and number of columns) will change. Is there a way to grab the "rest" of the columns without naming them or by their indexes?

Say I have this sample data:

```
data <- structure(list(Site = c("A", "B"), Group = c("1", "2"), grip = c("S", 
"H"), height = c("S", "T"), width = c("W", "N"), QA = c("Y", 
"N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

That looks like this:

```
  Site Group grip height width QA
1    A     1    S      S     W  Y
2    B     2    H      T     N  N
```

And sometimes the dataset will have more columns. Say I want to get columns `grip:QA`, without naming QA, or giving its index number. I tried the following:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = grip:everything(),
               names_to = "Name",
               values_to = "value")
```

But I get the warning `Warning message: In x:y : numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used`, and it doesn't pivot the way I want it to. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Comment: `pivot_longer(cols = -(Site:Group), ....`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `last_col`:

```r
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = grip:last_col(),
    names_to = "Name",
    values_to = "value"
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   Site  Group Name   value
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 A     1     grip   S    
#> 2 A     1     height S    
#> 3 A     1     width  W    
#> 4 A     1     QA     Y    
#> 5 B     2     grip   H    
#> 6 B     2     height T    
#> 7 B     2     width  N    
#> 8 B     2     QA     N
```

Or as another option exclude the columns you don't want to include when pivoting using `!` or `-`:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = !c(Site, Group),
    names_to = "Name",
    values_to = "value"
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   Site  Group Name   value
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 A     1     grip   S    
#> 2 A     1     height S    
#> 3 A     1     width  W    
#> 4 A     1     QA     Y    
#> 5 B     2     grip   H    
#> 6 B     2     height T    
#> 7 B     2     width  N    
#> 8 B     2     QA     N
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I wanted. I should've thought of the `!c(Site, Group)` on my own, but it's great to learn that `last_col()` function. Appreciate it greatly! Will accept the answer when the time block is up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `data.table`, here's a solution using `data.table::melt`:

```r
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(data), id.vars = 2:which(colnames(data) == "grip")-1)

#>    Site Group variable value
#> 1:    A     1     grip     S
#> 2:    B     2     grip     H
#> 3:    A     1   height     S
#> 4:    B     2   height     T
#> 5:    A     1    width     W
#> 6:    B     2    width     N
#> 7:    A     1       QA     Y
#> 8:    B     2       QA     N
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>